# PHP docker-php-api: filter specification (OpenAPI)

Tags: php, docker, openapi

I'm using [docker-php-api](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php-api) and need to use the function [imageList](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php-api/blob/659130166a797096902a158e1f648e2e0d0001d6/src/Client.php#L652) with tag filters.

The `queryParameters` are specified as YAML file in OpenAPI spec format [here (line 6045)](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php-api/blob/659130166a797096902a158e1f648e2e0d0001d6/docker-swagger.yaml):

```
parameters:
    - name: "all"
      in: "query"
      description: "Show all images. Only images from a final layer (no children) are shown by default."
      type: "boolean"
      default: false
    - name: "filters"
      in: "query"
      description: |
        A JSON encoded value of the filters (a `map[string][]string`) to process on the images list. Available filters:
        - `before`=(`<image-name>[:<tag>]`,  `<image id>` or `<image@digest>`)
        - `dangling=true`
        - `label=key` or `label="key=value"` of an image label
        - `reference`=(`<image-name>[:<tag>]`)
        - `since`=(`<image-name>[:<tag>]`,  `<image id>` or `<image@digest>`)
      type: "string"
    - name: "digests"
      in: "query"
      description: "Show digest information as a `RepoDigests` field on each image."
      type: "boolean"
      default: false
```

This query parameter specification is a valid sample:

```
$queryParameter = [
    'all' => true,
];
```

But how to specify filters as query parameter? The `filter` element is specified as

> A JSON encoded value of the filters (a `map[string][]string`) to
> process on the images list.

I tried

```
$queryParameter = [
    'filters' => json_encode([
        'map' => [
            'before' => [
                $imageTag
            ],
        ],
    ]) 
];
```

But this doesn't work and thows an `ImageListInternalServerErrorException`.